# Stacking movement bonuses

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement

- Absolute Steel stance from Tome of Battle
- Wind Stride boost from Tome of Battle

Wind Stride provides an enhancement bonus to land speed, while Absolute Steel proves an enhancement bonus to speed in general. I know enhancement bonuses don't stack, but in this case they modify slightly different things. Do these stack?

Comment: Can you comment on [HeyICanChan's comment below](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87213/stacking-movement-bonuses#comment197391_87214)? If they're right, then it'd be good for you to edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Your edit does not make your question clear at all. You have made an accurate statement. What is your *question* about that fact?

Comment: @KRyan ok i tried again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The bonuses don't stack

The 1st-level Desert Wind boost wind stride (*Tome of Battle* 56) grants a bonus *only* to the creature's land speed, while the 3rd-level Iron Heart stance absolute steel (*Tome of Battle* 66) grants the martial adept a +10 ft. enhancement bonus to the adept's speed generally.

As both are—eventually—identically named bonuses to the martial adept's land speed, the bonuses don't stack but overlap, so only one of the bonuses is realized (although were one of the bonuses to disappear, the other would remain).

That means, when the martial adept assumes the stance, the martial adept *really does* benefit from a +10 ft. enhancement bonus to his land speed, even though that 10 ft. bonus is applied individually to *all* of the martial adept's speeds that he possesses. (For example, the martial adept would gain a bonus to his swim speed if he had one, but would *not* suddenly and inexplicably gain, like, a burrow speed if he *didn't* already have one).

The stance's enhancement bonus to speed broadly prevents the boost from adding *another* +10 ft. enhancement bonus to the martial adept's land speed because the martial adept *already* has a +10 ft. enhancement bonus to land speed. (If it makes you feel any better—and it won't—because specific trumps general, the boost's specific enhancement bonus to land speed technically trumps the stance's general bonus to all speeds… not that *that* makes any real difference.)

To put this in a different context, for example, if an effect said that it granted a creature a +2 morale bonus on all the creature's ability scores, the creature couldn't add to that—or *stack*—an effect that granted the creature *only* a +2 morale bonus to its Strength score.

Answer (score 4):

*Absolute steel* and *wind stride* are both enhancement bonuses, and do not stack with one another. In fact, since *wind stride* applies only to land speeds, for non-land speeds they don’t even overlap—in those cases *absolute steel* is just the only one that applies. But in the case of land movement, both apply but do not stack due to having the same type.

Quick is an untyped bonus, and stacks with everything (except itself, but there is no way to get it twice anyway).

The stacking rules are all explained in the [basic rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#stacking). They are a fundamental part of the game and it is important you read them.